# Rebasing git branches on top of tracking branches

Tags: git, rebase, git-rebase, git-stash

Suppose you have a Git repository with a `master` branch tracking `origin/master` and a long-lived `release` branch tracking `origin/release`. Now, suppose that a `git fetch` operation has changed the tracking branches such that `release` is behind. Finally, suppose you have unstashed changes.

If we do `git rebase --autostash` while we are on master, then master will be up-to-date with its remote, and the unstashed changes will be preserved, short of a rebase/unstash conflict. The question is, if I am on `master` with unstashed changes (and possibly behind `origin/master`), what should I do in order to have `release` no longer behind `origin/release`?

My best guess is using some form of `git rebase --autostash --onto`, but I'm not sure what the rest of the arguments would be like. Maybe `git rebase --autostash --onto release origin/release release`?

Also, would it suffice to *reset* `release` to `origin/release` instead?

Comment: Do you need a local `release` branch-name at all? If not, consider just deleting it and using `origin/release` when you want to view or otherwise access the given commit.

Comment: Do you have new commits on your local copy of `master` and `release` that aren't on the remote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have new commits on your local copies of `master` and `release`, then yes, it would suffice to reset them to their remote counterparts without using `rebase`. Furthermore, you can achieve your example scenario without even checking out the branch:

If you are "on `master` with unstashed changes", and you wish to update `release` with `origin/release`. You can simply run the command:

```
git fetch
git branch -f release origin/release
```

However, if you are able to do that, then as torek points out [in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68568063/rebasing-git-branches-on-top-of-tracking-branches#comment121182725_68568063), you probably don't even need a local copy of `release`, since anytime you would reference it you can use `origin/release` instead.

Answer (score 0):

> if I am on master with unstashed changes (and possibly behind origin/master), what should I do in order to have release no longer behind origin/release?

Say

```
git fetch origin release:release
```

That does an effective pull of release without switching to it. The state of the branch you are on is irrelevant.